# Removing random buttons

Tags: objective-c, random

I'm generating buttons every second with a tag 1,2,3,etc. incrementing with each one made. A button is removed when a user clicks on it by using a method with (id)sender that triggers RemoveFromSuperview. Is there a way to delete several, random buttons at once without clicking on the specific button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is store references to those buttons in an `NSMutableArray`. But remember to remove them from the `NSMutableArray` as you remove the buttons with `removeFromSuperview`.